# Svelte SPA Router - Invalid component object error

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I'm using SvelteKit and [`svelte-spa-router`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-spa-router).

My file structure looks like the following:

```
src/
├─ assets/
├─ lib/
│  ├─ Navbar.svelte
│  ├─ Sidebar.svelte
├─ routes/
│  ├─ about/
│  │  ├─ index.svelte
│  ├─ contact/
│  │  ├─ index.svelte
│  ├─ products/
│  │  ├─ index.svelte
│  ├─ Test.svelte
│  ├─ index.svelte
│  ├─ __layout.svelte
├─ app.css
├─ app.html
```

**__layout.svelte:**

(As per the example in the link above.)

```
<script>
  import Router from 'svelte-spa-router'
  import Navbar from "$lib/Navbar.svelte";
  import Sidebar from "$lib/Sidebar.svelte";
  import Home from './index.svelte'
  import About from './about/index.svelte'
  import Contact from './contact/index.svelte'
  import Products from './products/index.svelte'
  import Test from './Test.svelte';

  const routes = {
    // Exact path
    '/': Home,
    '/about': About,
    '/contact': Contact,
    '/products': Products,
    '/test': Test
  }
</script>

<Navbar />

<Sidebar />

<Router {routes} />

<style>
</style>
```

**Error:**

```
Error: Invalid component object
    at new RouteItem (Router.svelte:303:23)
    at Router.svelte:432:28
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Router.svelte:431:31
    at Object.$$render ([Path to project]/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:1702:22)
    at eval (/src/routes/__layout.svelte:62:85)
    at Object.$$render ([Path to project]/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:1702:22)
    at eval (eval at instantiateModule ([Path to project]/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-fcec4469.js:67775:28), <anonymous>:55:122)
    at $$render ([Path to project]/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:1702:22)
    at Object.render ([Path to project]/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:1710:26)
```

**Console:**

[image: Console Text]

If I remove `<Router {routes} />` and use `<slot></slot>`, everything works fine.

The only thing I managed to find about this error was [this GitHub](https://github.com/ItalyPaleAle/svelte-spa-router/blob/master/Router.svelte) source code of `Router.svelte` (line `#301`), but it didn't help much.

I tried changing the names of the components like in the example, but the error was still thrown (I figured maybe the fact that they're all called the same might be a bug, I don't know...).

Manually navigating via `localhost:3000/[path]` throws the error as well, including `/test` path which is outside in the same path as the `__layout.svelte`. The latter I mention because in the first link I provided the author said:

> To display the router, in a Svelte component (usually App.svelte),
> first import the router component...

Usually from the examples I've seen, the structure you normally put in the `App.svelte` goes in the `__layout.svelte` and then the `index.svelte`, which serves as the "Home"/"Landing" page, automatically goes in the `<slot />` (and whatever other routes you might have) located in `__layout.svelte`, by default.

<s>Last but not least, dynamically importing them didn't work either.</s> See --> **Edit 3**

I understand a lot of the things I've tried probably have nothing to do with the problem, but the problem itself makes no sense to me. Like, why are the components getting passed as objects of a type the `Router` doesn't understand? `Test.svelte` literally only has `<h1>TEST COMPONENT</h1>` in it.

**Edit:**

Added the following code to my `__layout.svelte`'s `<script></script>` section:

```
// Contains logging information used by tests
let logbox = ''
// Handles the "conditionsFailed" event dispatched by the router when a component can't be loaded because one of its pre-condition failed
function conditionsFailed(event) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.error('Caught event conditionsFailed', event.detail)
  logbox += 'conditionsFailed - ' + JSON.stringify(event.detail) + '\n'
  // Replace the route
  replace('/wild/conditions-failed')
}
// Handles the "routeLoaded" event dispatched by the router after a route has been successfully loaded
function routeLoaded(event) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.info('Caught event routeLoaded', event.detail)
  logbox += 'routeLoaded - ' + JSON.stringify(event.detail) + '\n'
}
// Handles the "routeLoading" event dispatched by the router whie a route is being loaded
// If the route is dynamically imported, such as with the `import()` syntax, then there might be a delay before the route is loaded
function routeLoading(event) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.info('Caught event routeLoading', event.detail)
  logbox += 'routeLoading - ' + JSON.stringify(event.detail) + '\n'
}
// Handles event bubbling up from nested routes
function routeEvent(event) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.info('Caught event routeEvent', event.detail)
  logbox += 'routeEvent - ' + JSON.stringify(event.detail) + '\n'
}
```

After which I put the following below it, as shown in [this test example](https://github.com/ItalyPaleAle/svelte-spa-router/blob/master/test/app/src/App.svelte):

```
<Router 
  {routes} 
  on:conditionsFailed={conditionsFailed}
  on:routeLoaded={routeLoaded}
  on:routeLoading={routeLoading}
  on:routeEvent={routeEvent}
/>
```

None of these got called, there was only the red console message seen in the picture above.

**Edit 2:**

As suggested by **Thomas Hennes**, I replaced `<Router {routes} />` with each component individually in my `__layout.svelte` file, like so:

```
<script>
  import Router from 'svelte-spa-router'
  import Navbar from "$lib/Navbar.svelte";
  import Sidebar from "$lib/Sidebar.svelte";
  import Home from './index.svelte'
  import About from './about/index.svelte'
  import Contact from './contact/index.svelte'
  import Products from './products/index.svelte'
  import Test from './Test.svelte';

  const routes = {
    // Exact path
    '/': Home,
    //'/about': About,
    //'/contact': Contact,
    //'/products': Products,
    //'/test': Test
  }
</script>

<Navbar />

<Sidebar />

<Routes {routes} />

<style>
</style>
```

None of them worked.

**Edit 3:**

Funny thing, I noticed dynamically importing the routes crashes my local server. xD

```
const routes = {
  // Exact path
  '/': wrap({
        asyncComponent: () => import('./index.svelte')
  }),
  '/about': wrap({
        asyncComponent: () => import('./about/index.svelte')
  }),
  '/contact': wrap({
        asyncComponent: () => import('./contact/.svelte')
  }),
  '/products': wrap({
        asyncComponent: () => import('./products/.svelte')
  }),
  '/test': wrap({
        asyncComponent: () => import('./Test.svelte')
  }),
}
```

It doesn't matter which one I import, if I only import one of them or all of them at the same time.

This is the console output of this adventure:

```
window is not defined
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at getLocation (Router.svelte:38:31)
    at start (Router.svelte:59:23)
    at Object.subscribe ([Path to project]/node_modules/svelte/store/index.js:51:20)
    at Router.svelte:493:36
    at Object.$$render ([Path to project]/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:1702:22)
    at eval (/src/routes/__layout.svelte:112:85)
    at Object.$$render ([Path to project]/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:1702:22)
    at eval (eval at instantiateModule ([Path to project]/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-fcec4469.js:67775:28), <anonymous>:55:122)
    at $$render ([Path to project]/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:1702:22)
    at Object.render ([Path to project]/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:1710:26)
history is not defined
ReferenceError: history is not defined
    at Router.svelte:455:10
    at Object.$$render ([Path to project]/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:1702:22)
    at eval (/src/routes/__layout.svelte:112:85)
    at Object.$$render ([Path to project]/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:1702:22)
    at eval (eval at instantiateModule ([Path to project]/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-fcec4469.js:67775:28), <anonymous>:55:122)
    at $$render ([Path to project]/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:1702:22)
    at Object.render ([Path to project]/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:1710:26)
    at render_response (file://[Path to project]/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/ssr.js:561:28)
    at async respond_with_error (file://[Path to project]/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/ssr.js:1148:10)
    at async respond$1 (file://[Path to project]/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/ssr.js:1392:4)
/node_modules/svelte-spa-router/Router.svelte:413
            const match = routesList[i].match(newLoc.location);
                                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'location')
    at eval (/node_modules/svelte-spa-router/Router.svelte:413:45)
    at Object.subscribe ([Path to project]/node_modules/svelte/store/index.js:53:9)
    at eval (/node_modules/svelte-spa-router/Router.svelte:406:29)
    at Object.$$render ([Path to project]/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:1702:22)
    at eval (/src/routes/__layout.svelte:112:85)
    at Object.$$render ([Path to project]/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:1702:22)
    at eval (eval at instantiateModule ([Path to project]/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-fcec4469.js:67775:28), <anonymous>:55:122)
    at $$render ([Path to project]/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:1702:22)
    at Object.render ([Path to project]/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:1710:26)
    at render_response (file://[Path to project]/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/ssr.js:561:28)
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing your `<Router {routes} />` component with all individual route components one by one? I.e. `<Home />` then `<About />` etc. It'll help you isolate the component(s) that are causing the issue and get you on the right path. Don't hesitate to update your question with the outcome of those tests if you still need help.

Comment: @ThomasHennes Just did as you suggested, but none of them produced any issues.

Comment: So when you have a single route definition in your `routes` object the router actually works properly? My idea was to replace the `<Router {routes} />` statement altogether, with `<Home />` first, then `<About />`, etc., so as to test each component individually, in hope that maybe a component was breaking. But if your router works for every single route individually, it's really odd. Have you tried adding routes inncrementally? First with `routes = { '/': Home }` then with `routes = { '/': Home, '/about': About }`, etc.?

Comment: "So when you have a single route definition in your routes object the router actually works properly?" - No, I meant that none of them worked and the same error persisted. I'll edit my question to clarify that.

Comment: Oh I just noticed you are using SvelteKit and not Svelte! `svelte-spa-router` as its name indicates, is meant to provide a routing solution for client-side Svelte projects (i.e. not SvelteKit projects). SvelteKit provides its own framework for handling routes. More importantly, `svelte-spa-router` is not meant to run server-side, which SvelteKit does (at the very least on initial page load). You should refer to SvelteKit routing and adapt your code accordingly.

Comment: Oh, rip in peperoni. That makes sense. They must be conflicting with each other somehow. You saved me a lot of headaches. Post this as an answer and I'll be more than happy to mark it. :3

Comment: [This](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#routing) is where you will want to get started.

Comment: I actually saw that part of the Docs, but since my whole pages would refresh when changing routes, which caused the transitions/animations in my `<Navbar />` to replay every time I went to a new page, I assumed SvelteKit didn't work as an actual SPA. My previous VueJS (and its corresponding router) experience might have given me a wrong understanding/idea of things.

Comment: If you put your `<Navbar />` etc. in a `__layout.svelte` component inside your routing tree, then these shared components won't reload when navigating to child routes on the client-side. Only the `<slot />` contents will be re-rendered. Fully reloading the page *will* refresh all page components, however, as should be expected.

Comment: @ThomasHennes That's what I thought the case would be as well. Unfortunately this happens -> when I first load the page, the `<Navbar />` animation/transition plays, then I click on "About" and it plays again, then I click on "Contact" and it plays once more, BUT if I were to click the "Back" button of the browser or click on the "About" link in said navigation bar, the animation/transition doesn't play. In other words, it plays only on parts of the website I haven't visited yet, but once I do, no matter what way I use to visit an already visited page, the animation/transition doesn't happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240567/discussion-between-thomas-hennes-and-doombringerbg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`svelte-spa-router` is designed as a routing solution for [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/) projects (which are client-side only). It is not meant to function in server-side rendered SvelteKit projects.

[SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/), which is a universal (CSR + SSR) framework, provides [its own routing solution](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#routing), which will work client-side and server-side.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add, in your **src/routes/+layout.js** file:

```
export const ssr = false;
```

I had the same error with current version of SvelteKit and it worked for me.

[Page options](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#ssr)